# addClass if contains match

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<li class="widgetcontainer widget_text" id="text-3">
   <h3 class="widgettitle">Static Ad</h3>
   <div class="textwidget"><img alt="" src="static/announcement.png"></div>
</li>
```

jQuery:

```
if( $('.widget_text')[0] ) {
    $('.widgettitle').each(function() {
      if ( $(this).containts('Static Ad') ) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('myclass');
      }
    }); 
}
```

... isn't working. Neither:

```
if( $('.widget_text')[0] ) {
    $('.widget_text').each(function() {
      if ( $(this).children('h3:contains:("Static Ad")') ) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('static-ad');
      }
    }); 
}
```

How do I fix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>You have a typo: `if ( $(this).contains('Static Ad') ) {`</del>

Try:

```
$('.widgettitle:contains("Static Ad")').parent().addClass('myclass');
```

or

```
$('.widget_text').each(function() {
   if ( $(this).children('h3:contains("Static Ad")').length > 0 ) {
     $(this).addClass('static-ad');
   }
})
```

You have an additional  colon `:` in your code (remove it) and I think you have to remove `parent()`.

Besides that, there is no need to test for `$('.widget_text')[0]`. If there is no element with class `widget_text`, `$('.widget_text').each()` won't do anything anyway ;)

Comment: `.contains()` is not used this way. It checks to see if a DOM node is within another DOM node.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.widgettitle:contains("Static Ad")').parent().addClass('myclass');
```

Read more here:

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

A demo here:

http://jsbin.com/alega3/2

Answer (score 1):

[`jQuery.contains`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/) is to test if one DOM node is within another DOM node.

Try this instead:

```
$('.widget_text').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('.widgettitle').text().indexOf('Static Ad') > -1;
}).addClass('myclass');
```

This will select all elements with *widget_text* class, filter out those that do not have a descendant with *widgettitle* class with “Static Ad” in its text, and add *myclass* to it.